# C++ - Reference where to put it?

Tags: c++, function, reference

Hi I have a basic question and sorry if it's a duplicate, but I can't seem to find what I'm looking for with google.

I have this function signature:

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream& o, const Test& t) {...}
```

And the ordering of the reference "&" confuses me as sometimes its at the front of the function name/arguments instead:

```
ostream &operator<<(ostream &o, const Test &t) {...}
```

does this make any difference or has a different meaning?
Any explanation would be brilliant, thank you!

EDIT: Also they both seem to work fine when compiling but which one should I be using?

Comment: The C++ compiler doesn't care either way; it would just as happily accept `ostream&operator<<(ostream&o,const Test&t)` or `ostream & operator << ( ostream & o , const Test & t )`. Most humans prefer `Test& t`, in my experience.

Comment: Use consistent naming. See how other references are used in the project you're working on, and do the same.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> does this make any difference or has a different meaning?

It makes no difference.

> Any explanation would be brilliant

In general, white-space only changes the meaning of the program where it's needed to separate tokens. Punctuation tokens like `&` don't need separating from alphanumeric tokens, so you'll get the same sequence of tokens here (`ostream`, `&`, `o`) however you space them.

> which one should I be using?

Whichever looks more appealing to you. Or, if you work in a feudal environment, whichever your overlord commands.

Personally, I put space on both sides of the modifier, because I regard it as a separate "word" to the other tokens. Others have different aesthetics, regarding it as modifying either the type or the variable, and space it accordingly.

Comment: Thanks! I noticed it complained with putting "&" at the front of the object type like: 

"& ostream operator<<(&ostream o, const &Test t) {...}"

so thought ordering mattered more.

Comment: @Mayron: Yes, the order matters a lot: `& ostream` is meaningless. But spacing doesn't matter (except when it's needed to separate tokens).

Answer (score 2):

There is no difference between them and both are exactly the same. Spaces don't matter and only thing that matters is `&` is between the `ostream` and `operator<<`
All of these are equivalent:

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream& o, const Test& t) {...}
ostream & operator<<(ostream & o, const Test & t) {...}
ostream &operator<<(ostream &o, const Test &t) {...}
ostream & operator<<(ostream  & o, const Test    & t) {...}
```

and other combinations you can think of.

Answer (score 1):

It is purely a matter of style and above all you should try to be consistent within your own code, or within the code that you are maintaining for readability.

There are differing philosophical opinions on which is best. `ostream& o` draws attention to the fact that object `o` has type `ostream&`, while `ostream &o` is more suggestive of the fact that `o` is a reference to a `ostream`.

Personally, I like to stick it on the end of the type.